# Getting 'Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined' in console

Tags: javascript

```js
const square = document.querySelectorAll('square');
const mole = document.querySelectorAll('mole');
const timeLeft = document.querySelector('#time-left');
let score = document.querySelector('#score');

let result = 0;

function randomSquare() {
    square.forEach(className => {
        className.classList.remove('mole');
    });
    let randomPosition = square[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)];
    randomPosition.classList.add('mole');

    //assign the id of the randomPosition to hitPosition for us to use later
    hitPosition = randomPosition.id;
}
 
square.forEach(id => {
    id.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        if(id.id === hitPosition) {
            result = result + 1;
            score.textContent = result;
        }
    });
});

function moveMole() {
    let timerId = null;
    timerId = setInterval(randomSquare, 1000);
}

moveMole();
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Whack a mole</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Whack a mole!</h1>

            <h2>Your score:</h2>
            <h2 id="time-left">60</h2>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="square" id="1"></div>
            <div class="square mole" id="2"></div>
            <div class="square" id="3"></div>
            <div class="square" id="4"></div>
            <div class="square" id="5"></div>
            <div class="square" id="6"></div>
            <div class="square" id="7"></div>
            <div class="square" id="8"></div>
            <div class="square" id="9"></div>
        </div>
    
        </body>
        <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

I'm following an online tutorial on making grid games with javascript and I'm getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined at randomSquare (app.js:13)

I have exactly the same coding as the video but don't know why it's not working.
Can anyone inform me as to what i'm missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: You've missed the class selector. Use something like ```const square = document.querySelectorAll('.square');``` . Add the missing dot before the selector.

Comment: The querySelector and querySelectorAll methods select DOM elment(s) using css selectors, so you need to write a valid css selector to get the desired DOM element(s)

Comment: Thanks! That solved it Sajeeb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set improper querySelector. document.querySelectorAll('square') and document.querySelectorAll('mole')  will look for html tag with these names respectively.

```js
const square = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
    const mole = document.querySelectorAll('.mole');
    const timeLeft = document.querySelector('#time-left');
    let score = document.querySelector('#score');

    let result = 0;

    function randomSquare() {
        square.forEach(className => {
            className.classList.remove('mole');
        });
        let randomPosition = square[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)];
        randomPosition.classList.add('mole');

        //assign the id of the randomPosition to hitPosition for us to use later
        hitPosition = randomPosition.id;
    }
     
    square.forEach(id => {
        id.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            if(id.id === hitPosition) {
                result = result + 1;
                score.textContent = result;
            }
        });
    });

    function moveMole() {
        let timerId = null;
        timerId = setInterval(randomSquare, 1000);
    }

    moveMole();
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Whack a mole</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>

            <h1>Whack a mole!</h1>

                <h2>Your score:</h2>
                <h2 id="time-left">60</h2>
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="square" id="1"></div>
                <div class="square mole" id="2"></div>
                <div class="square" id="3"></div>
                <div class="square" id="4"></div>
                <div class="square" id="5"></div>
                <div class="square" id="6"></div>
                <div class="square" id="7"></div>
                <div class="square" id="8"></div>
                <div class="square" id="9"></div>
            </div>
        
            </body>
            <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Md, 
I don't know why they weren't in the video either but I should have been paying attention myself!

Comment: @Johnroiste, which video you was referring?

Comment: It was about making grid based games by free code camp